# Laravel Switching Database with respect to User Data from Main Database

Tags: php, database, laravel

Current Scenario,
I have a main database where I have the user database related information stored . ie. client table .
Now when the user tries to login I check in my main database where the user exist or not and if exist get the database related information . and I made a middleware to switch the database connection . Now the problem is here.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $clientData = Client::where('email', $request['email'])
        ->where('workspace', $request['workspace'])
        ->first();
    if ($clientData) {
        $db_name = $clientData->db_name;
        $db_config_name = $clientData->db_config_name;
        $db_username = $clientData->db_username;
        $db_password = $clientData->db_password;
        DB::disconnect('mysql');
        Config::set("database.connections.mysql.database",  $db_name);
        Config::set("database.connections.mysql.username", $db_username);
        Config::set("database.connections.mysql.password", $db_password);

        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error_message', 'No data'], 500);
    }
}
```

when I do this it works .. but what i wanted was to use the data from database.config . if I do

```
$clientData = Client::where('email', $request['email'])
        ->where('workspace', $request['workspace'])
        ->first();
    if ($clientData) {
        $db_name = $clientData->db_name;
        $db_config_name = $clientData->db_config_name;
        $db_username = $clientData->db_username;
        $db_password = $clientData->db_password;
        DB::disconnect('mysql');
        Config::set("database.connections" . $db_config_name . "database",  $db_name);
        Config::set("database.connections" . $db_config_name . "database", $db_username);
        Config::set("database.connections" . $db_config_name . "database", $db_password);

        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error_message', 'No data'], 500);
    }
```

and I receive "test1" in $db_config_name this is what I have in `database.config`

```
 'test1' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => 'db_test',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

this second approach doesnot work ie. it returns the data from the default Database `mysql` . Can anyone explain me why this is happening and if I do the first approach I wont need to store data in `database.config` right ? Would love to hear suggestion.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to use the service provider rather than a middleware to connect to the database.

First of all purge the database connection cache

```
DB::purge('test1');
```

Set the database connection details

```
Config::set("database.connections.test1.host", "");
Config::set("database.connections.test1.database", "");
Config::set("database.connections.test1.username", "");
Config::set("database.connections.test1.password", "");
```

Now change the database default database connection to test1

```
DB::setDefaultConnection("test1");
```

> Note: Do not store the database password in the plain format in the
> database.

```
class DBSwitchProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(){
        // First purge the configuration to remove config details from cache 
        DB::purge('test1');

        // set the database config details 
        Config::set("database.connections.test1.host", "host_value");
        Config::set("database.connections.test1.database", "database_name");
        Config::set("database.connections.test1.username", "database_user");
        Config::set("database.connections.test1.password", "db_password");
        
        // if current db connection is test1 
        // reconnect the database 
        if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName() == "test1"){
            DB::reconnect("test1");
        }else{
            // change the default databse to the 
            DB::setDefaultConnection("test1");
        } 
        
        
    }
}
```